# request.FILES and request.POST.get in Django

Tags: html, django

I need the following code to work as written:

```
testo = request.POST.get('testo')
lang = request.POST.get('lang')

  
audio = request.FILES['audio']
fs = FileSystemStorage()
filename = fs.save(audio.name, audio)
uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
```

The problem is that for request.FILES the form is required to be - enctype="multipart/form-data" -
If I enter this enctype after request.POST.get doesn't work anymore.

My form instead is like this:

```
<form action="{% url 'app' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <textarea name="testo" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <label for="lang">Scegli lingua:</label>
      <select name="lang" id="">
          <option value="it">Italiano</option>
          <option value="en">Inglese</option>
          <option value="es">Spagnolo</option>
      </select>
      <input type="file" name="audio" id="">
      <button type="submit">INVIA</button>
  </form>
```

With my form I can get the text to work, but I can't get request.FILES to work!!!

Any solution?

Unfortunately I can't with my form. I need it as is, but I need something that allows me to make text and files work in Django.

Comment: [`enctype="multipart/form-data"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/enctype).

Comment: Just add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Comment: "_The problem is that for request.FILES the form is required to be - `enctype="multipart/form-data"`_" Then just do that what's the problem really?

Answer (score 0):

Add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `form`. It should work without any issues:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: So it gives me problems when I do request.POST.get